# How to inject a dependency of a constructor with multiple variables to spring xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a test class created. I need to run the test file using spring dependency injection . I am using the XML method.

How to define a bean for Inventory in your XML configuration?

Testfile constructor:

```
public VendingMachineServiceLayerImplTest() {

Inventory testItem = new Inventory(2);
testItem.setItemName("Item2");
testItem.setCost(new BigDecimal("4.50"));
testItem.setNoOfItems(0);

VendingMachineDao dao = new VendingMachineDaoStubImpl(testItem);
VendingMachineAuditDao auditDao = new VendingMachineAuditDaoStubImpl();
VendingMachineChange change = new VendingMachineChange();

service = new VendingMachineServiceLayerImpl(dao, auditDao, change);
}
```

Bean Definition in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dao" 
   class="mthree.vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineDaoFileImpl"/>
   
<bean id="daoStub" 
   class="vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineDaoStubImpl"/>
   
<bean id="change" 
   class="vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineAuditDaoStubImpl"/>
<bean id="change" class="vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineChange"/>
   
<bean id="serviceLayer" 
   class="vendingmachine.service.VendingMachineServiceLayerImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="dao"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="auditDaoStub"/>  
    <constructor-arg ref="change"/>           
</bean>
```

Inventory Class

```
public class Inventory {
    private int itemNumber;
    private String itemName;
    private BigDecimal cost;
    private int noOfItems;

    
    public Inventory(int itemNumber){
        this.itemNumber=itemNumber;
    }
    
    public int getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }
//other getters and setters
}
```

How can i inject the constructor with the object? I have tried adding properties but the test error occurred as the properties couldn't parse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking? Which constructor? Inject what object? What does that snippet of code up top have to do with the XML configuration? Please rephrase or otherwise clarify your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to define a bean for `Inventory` in your XML configuration?

Comment: @Savior Yes please

Comment: Just do it the same way you did for all your other `<bean>` declarations. Except add `<property>` for each property of your `Inventory` class. Then use a `<constructor-arg />` again with a `ref` referring to the `Inventory` bean.

Comment: <bean id="inventory" class="mthree.vendingmachine.dto.Inventory">
         <property name = "itemNumber" value = "2"/>
         <property name = "itemName" value = "Item1"/>
         <property name = "cost" value = "5"/>
         <property name = "noOfItems" value = "100"/>
    </bean>
   
   <bean id="dao2" class="mthree.vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineDaoFileImpl">
      <property name = "inventoryItem" ref = "inventory"/> 
   </bean>

Comment: Yeah, that looks about right.

Comment: Oh, pass the `itemNumber` as a `constructor-arg` or remove that constructor in the class.

Comment: @Savior . It worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include the value that is in the constructor in the `<constructor-arg>` tag and other properties in the `<property>` tag in the `Inventory Class` as follows.

```
   <bean id="daoStub" 
       class="mthree.vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineDaoStubImpl"/>
   
    <bean id="auditDaoStub" 
       class="mthree.vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineAuditDaoStubImpl"/>
    
    <bean id="change" class="mthree.vendingmachine.service.VendingMachineChange"/>
   
    
    <bean id="inventory" class="vendingmachine.dto.Inventory">
         <constructor-arg name = "itemNumber" value = "2"/>
         <property name = "itemName" value = "Item2"/>
         <property name = "cost" value = "5"/>
         <property name = "noOfItems" value = "0"/>
    </bean>
   
   <bean id="dao" class="vendingmachine.dao.VendingMachineDaoStubImpl"> 
      <constructor-arg ref = "inventory"/> 
   </bean>
   
       <bean id="serviceLayer" 
       class="vendingmachine.service.VendingMachineServiceLayerImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="dao"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="auditDaoStub"/>  
        <constructor-arg ref="change"/>           
    </bean>
```